# How do I unbind a Backbone Collection fetch callback?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

If I have a view that has a collection that is fetched in the initialize function, but the view needs cleaned up before the fetch returns, how do I unbind the success and/or error callbacks?

So, with code like this:

```
Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function () {
    this.collection = new MyColl();
    this.collection.fetch({
      success: this.successCallback,
      error: this.errorCallback
    });
  },
  close: function () {
    // what goes here to keep successCallback and errorCallback from being called?
  }
});
```

When I call myView.close() to clean it up (in this case to show another view), and I don't want to be calling successCallback later (after view "cleanup").

I've tried:

```
close: function () {
  this.collection.unbind('reset');
}
```

But the collection doesn't seem to have a this event listed in its _callbacks internal var after fetch, so unbind doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 1):

You could always just add a logical flag to this.successCallback and this.errorCallback that checks if this.close has been called:

```
Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function () {
    this.collection = new MyColl();
    this.collection.fetch({
      success: this.successCallback,
      error: this.errorCallback
    });
  },
  close: function () {
     // do stuff
     this.closed = true;
  },
  successCallback: function() {
    if(this.closed) return;
    //Do stuff
  }
});
```

Alternatively, you should not really be setting up your events in this manner.  It is much more "backbone-ish" if you instead do something similar to:

```
Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function () {
    this.collection = new MyColl();
    this.collection.bind('reset', this.SuccessCallback);
    this.collection.bind('error', this.errorCallback);
  },
  close: function () {
     // do stuff
     this.collection.unbind('reset', this.successCallback);
     this.collection.unbind('error', this.errorCallback);
  },
  successCallback: function() {
    //Do stuff
  }
});
```

Comment: Fair enough.  This makes sense.  It would be nicer to not have to store extra state and just unbind the success and error callbacks from the fetch options.